# accessing static (class) variables defined in a subclass from a superclass

Tags: javascript

I have some classes that share identical methods and are distinguished only by a few static (aka class) variables.  My thought is to put the common methods into a base class that accesses the static variables.

Here is a solution that works, but it seems like a real *cough* kludge.  Is there a better / more idiomatic way to do this?

```
"use strict";

// common code
function Base() { }
Base.prototype.f1 = function() {
    console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(this).constructor.VAR1); // this feels really really wrong!
}
Base.prototype.f2 = function() {
    console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(this).constructor.VAR2); // ditto
}

// specialization A
function SubA() {  Base.call(this); }
SubA.prototype = Object.create(Base.prototype);
SubA.prototype.constructor = SubA;
SubA.VAR1 = "suba v1";
SubA.VAR2 = "suba v2";

// specialization B
function SubB() { Base.call(this); }
SubB.prototype = Object.create(Base.prototype);
SubB.prototype.constructor = SubB;
SubB.VAR1 = "subb v1";
SubB.VAR2 = "subb v2";
```

This works as expected:

```
> var a = new SubA();
> var b = new SubB();
> a.f1()
suba v1
undefined
> b.f2()
subb v2
undefined
```

### an alternative

Of course I could write methods to encapsulate the differences between SubA and SubB.  The syntax is less tortured, but it still feels wrong to write methods that are essentially behaving like static variables:

```
"use strict";

function Base() { }
Base.prototype.f1 = function() {
    console.log(this.getVar1());
}
Base.prototype.f2 = function() {
    console.log(this.getVar2());
}

function SubA() {  Base.call(this); }
SubA.prototype = Object.create(Base.prototype);
SubA.prototype.constructor = SubA;
SubA.prototype.getVar1 = function() { return 'suba v1'; }
SubA.prototype.getVar2 = function() { return 'suba v2'; }

function SubB() { Base.call(this); }
SubB.prototype = Object.create(Base.prototype);
SubB.prototype.constructor = SubB;
SubB.prototype.getVar1 = function() { return 'subb v1'; }
SubB.prototype.getVar2 = function() { return 'subb v2'; }

> var a = new SubA();
> var b = new SubB();
> a.f1()
suba v1
undefined
> b.f2()
subb v2
undefined
```

Comment: Not sure if there is anything wrong it. Why not just add getVar1 and getVar2 methods in the Base class as well? have it return null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a particular reason to put `VAR1` and `VAR2` in the class objects themselves rather than in their prototypes? If not, things become much simpler:

```
function Base() { }
Base.prototype.f1 = function() {
  console.log(this.VAR1);
};
Base.prototype.f2 = function() {
  console.log(this.VAR2);
};

// specialization A
function SubA() {  Base.call(this); }
SubA.prototype = Object.create(Base.prototype);
SubA.prototype.constructor = SubA;
SubA.prototype.VAR1 = "suba v1";
SubA.prototype.VAR2 = "suba v2";

// specialization B
function SubB() { Base.call(this); }
SubB.prototype = Object.create(Base.prototype);
SubB.prototype.constructor = SubB;
SubB.prototype.VAR1 = "subb v1";
SubB.prototype.VAR2 = "subb v2";
```

The above code passes your tests.

Comment: I think this is the correct answer.  For some reason, I'd convinced myself that `SubA.prototype.VAR1 = "suba v1"` made every instance of SubA have extra memory slots allocated.  But I now see that was just a misconception.  Unless it wasn't :).

Comment: Prototype is an object just like any other, it's in memory only once, no matter how many instances of the class there are.

Comment: Chalk it up to "brain bubble".  Thanks.  Maybe this will help someone else.